# XPS (Extreme Memory Profile) causing Skyrim bug to speed-stutter

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, performance, hardware, framerate

I just upgraded from an socket AM3 790FX X4 at 3.1GHz (max OC) to an FX8350 AM3+ / 990FX with a Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD3 motherboard. I've kept the 2x4GB of G.Skill F3-17000CL11-4GBSR RAM from the AM3 in the AM3+ rig.

It seems the faster the RAM speed is the more the Skyrim stutter bug occurs. It actually speeds up the game for I would estimate about 50-200 milliseconds so after the stutter stops if you've been running forward in the game you're several feet ahead of where you previously were. This happens about 20-40 times a *minute*.

I disabled all the "Advanced CPU Features" in my bios and set the RAM to 1333MHz. After narrowing down what features did or did not effect the game play I've determined that the speed of the RAM itself has been causing the problems. The bios RAM speed without XPS (Extreme Memory Profile) only boots up to 1,600MHz. To get to the full 2,133MHz I have to use either XPS profile. However even at 1,600MHz I've noticed the stuttering bug perhaps once every few minutes so I can't say it's explicitly the XPS.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find anything even remotely close to being on-topic any where after a lot of searching. Yes, I've reinstalled the game and yes this bug occurs even in the menus and loading screen so saved games themselves are not the issue. After saving a game with the bug, setting the RAM to normal speed the bug is not "inherited" through the saved game.

Comment: Sounds like you have another bottleneck somewhere else.  Possibly your hard drive.  Does this happen with any other games, or is this specific to Skyrim only?

Comment: @fbueckert SSD, added link to my specs.

Comment: A piece of software was causing this issue, when I'm not working and get a chance I will narrow it down to which software and answer the question in case anyone else is having this same problem.

Comment: @John - Were you able to narrow this down at all?

Comment: @Robotnik I had completely forgotten about this and extremely odd for me that I did not post an answer as I hate it when I come across *exactly* the only on-topic thread anywhere and there is no answer.

I would reinstall the game and if that doesn't work reinstall Windows altogether. As much as that sucks each Windows install has it's own temperament.